# Implementing an IEnumerable<T> datastructure

Tags: c#, data-structures, ienumerable

I came across the following code that implements a Binary Tree. For facilitating foreach, `IEnumerable` is implemented.  Is this the easiest way to make foreach work? I don't understand why two `GetEnumerator()` functions are needed.

```
public class BinaryTree<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
 ..   
        public IEnumerator<T> InOrderTraversal()
        {
            ...
            yield return curr.Value;    
            ...         
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return InOrderTraversal();
        }


        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One returns `IEnumerator<T>` the other returns `IEnumerator`.  This is so that legacy code that was written before generics were introduced in .NET can still work with this data structure.

Comment: Suppose I don't care about legacy code, why can't I remove the non-generic `GetEnumerator` function? It won't compile.

Comment: That is because you implement IEnumerable<T>, which also inherits from IEnumerable which has the legacy GetEnumerator() as part of it's interface.